# File operations: Java (can't find file)

Tags: java, eclipse

```
try {
     File makefile = new File("jk.txt");
     FileWriter fwrite = new FileWriter(makefile);
     fwrite.write(temp);
     fwrite.flush();

} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where does the file get created in this code snippet? I can't find my file in my PC.

Comment: @home...before clicking the post as unuseful,i guess thepeople need to know that the coder may have tried the most obvious routes.I have searched in my computer for your kind information and cant find it.That is the reason i had posted it so that i wanted to know that whether the code has a bug or not and if not what possible reasons may be that the file is not getting created

Comment: Using Eclipse kind of messes with where the file goes, it goes where the Eclipse build path is. You can get the path where it is within the program as well like @MichaelBesteck 's answer.

Answer (score 3):

To print out the path where the file is created:

```
File f = new File(".");
System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
```

or

```
System.out.println(makefile.getCanonicalPath());
```

Comment: thanx man!..Stackoverflow really requires people like you...rather than those who downvote for fun sake without even help!!..thnx again.I had messed up with my root quiet badly that is why couldnt find the file

Comment: @user1485323 StackOverflow requires people to do some research before posting a new question that may be already solved. Or, a least, read the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) and ask about what didn't you understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this on Eclipse, the file should be on the project root.

If you're running this standalone, the file should be created on the current directory.

Comment: it is not.Is there an another way of creating files than this?

Answer (score 1):

It is created in the current path (probably the project root) since you don't set a path for the file when you create it.